# SCSS path is not working with mixin or variables in app.scss (main.scss)

Tags: css, sass, path, scss-mixins

I have a problem with the SCSS path. I have a folder structure. You can see it first image. The problem is that I imported all scss in app.scss. Files of components work, but pages of components don't read `mixin` and `variables`. First of all, I thought that It's a syntax error but I could not find it.

[image]

My app.scss

```
@import "./abstracts/variables.scss";
@import "./abstracts/mixins.scss";

@import "./components/Header.module.scss";
@import "./components/Footer.module.scss";

@import "./pages/Home.module.scss";
```

If I write `$mainColor` in Header.module.scss, there is no problem and the app works. But in `pages` folder, I have to write `@import` and I don't want to write it.

Home.module.scss

```
@import "../abstracts/variables.scss";
@import "../abstracts/mixins.scss";

.main-section {
  .main-section-context {
    @include flex-box(center, center);
    
  }
}
```

If I deleted `import` , the screen gives

```
SassError: Undefined mixin.
   ╷
13 │     @include flex-box(center, center);
   │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  styles\pages\Home.module.scss 13:5  root stylesheet
```

Comment: The actual mixin is missing in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I am spitballing here because I don't entirely understand your project, but make sure the order of your imports is correct. for example, if you import your variables after home, the home will not read it. it looks like thats not the problem specifically